# mysql join to union of constants

Tags: php, mysql, union

I have a mysql table which stores a range between two columns like so:

```
id  start  end
 1      1    9
 2     20   49
```

I need to create a query which will allow the user to submit a list of up to 10,000 integer values, and it needs to check if the value is within range or not. I want to avoid running 10,000 separate queries. I would like a dataset like the following, where PARAM is one of the 10,000 integer values the user submits:

```
start  end  PARAM
    1    9      4
   20   49     18
    1    9      6
    1    9      8
```

I thought about doing it with an extended WHERE clause, like start>=:PARAM AND end<=:PARAM, but I will only get ranges from this, and in the application have to loop through each param and find a matching range.

I saw other examples with unions but haven't attempted this before.

I also thought of inserting to a temporary table, select using a join, and emptying it but do not know if it would be more efficient.

Comment: How would you send those parameters other than a long string? You would then have to split that string and iterate over each number in it checking if it's inside the limits, storing a boolean flag along. You cannot embed such logic in a simple query. Either use a stored procedure or do it server-side. I'd recommend you do it server-side, there is no reason for doing it in the database (also there's a query length limit you most certainly will hit with 10000 integers).

Comment: ok makes sense. Hitting that string limit could end in running hundreds of queries. Better to pull the rows and loop through server side.

Comment: Doing it in a stored proc on the DB would move some strain away from your application server and may be faster (no more transporting 10000 integers from DB to app) but evidently you'd then have application logic outside the application, and that's not really desirable. Weight your benefits carefully.

Comment: add all user input to temporary table, then perform `INSERT SELECT ...`

Comment: Yes that will improve it. I found even with extended inserts I will still hit query string limit. Code's working now and if it's a problem I will look into file uploads only.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a long query, a where cause with 5,000 conditions, and breaking it up that way. The table is too large to pull into memory in a server side loop.

If it becomes an issue I plan on refactoring the code to have server save the parameters to a file and run a query on the mysql server directly, either dumping them into a table or creating the cube to hold the matches.